# How much nitrogen in fertilizer

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I’m trying a little exercise for fun in chemistry but I don’t find where I’m wrong.
Here it is:

In $\pu{2 kg}$ of a fertilizer, $\pu{39.7 mass\%}$ is $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$, and $\pu{15.2 mass\%}$ is $\ce{NH4NO3}$.

How much nitrogen (in $\pu{kg}$) contains this sample?

So I calculate the molar mass of both, which is $M(\ce{(NH4)2SO4}) = \pu{132 g/mol}$ and $M(\ce{NH4NO3}) = \pu{80 g/mol}$.

And then I calculate the number of mol of both so there is 39.7/132 = 0.3 mol and 15.2/80=0.19 mol of each substance

And then I figure out how much mol of nitrogen there is, so in 1 mol of $\ce{(NH4)2SO4}$ there is 2 mol of N and same for the other

So finally we have $2 \cdot 0.3 + 2 \cdot 0.19 = 0.98$ mol of N in the whole fertilizer and finally the mass of N is $\pu{0.98 mol}/\pu{14 g mol-1} = \pu{0.07 g}$.
And multiply by $\pu{2 kg}$ of fertiliser, we have $\pu{0.14 kg}$ of nitrogen.

But it seems the true answer is $\approx \pu{270 g}$.

So where is it wrong ?

Comment: First thing wrong was inconsistency of unit usage. Other things just followed as playing with numbers and wrong units seemed right.

Comment: (39.7 g/100 g) / ( 132 g/mol ) = (0.3 mol/ 100 g)

Comment: To get a mass from the amount of substance, you have to multiply by the molar mass. If you carry the units, you would see that dividing by the molar mass is incorrect for that step.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Note, *chemical* information may be advantageously formatted using on ChemSE with [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). Take moment to familiarize with this. You are encouraged to use it in the body of questions, answers, and comments. Because it is something special not all web browsers understand well, *do not* use it in the title of questions or answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are two mistakes in your calculation. Everything is correct to the point where you get $\pu{0.98 mol}$ of $\ce{N}$. You do not mention it, but this value is valid for a total mass of fertilizer of $\pu{100 g}$, because you started from $\pu{39.7 g}$ of fertilizer. And these $\pu{39.7 g}$ correspond to  $\pu{39.7 wt\%}$ of $\pu{100 g}$.

Now first mistake is the calculation of the mass of $\pu{0.98 mol}$ of $\ce{N}$. As $\pu{1 mol}$ of $\ce{N}$ weighs $\pu{14 g}$, $\pu{0.98 mol}$ weighs $\pu{0.98 mol} \cdot \pu{14 g/mol} = \pu{13.72 g}$. This is the amount of nitrogen in $\pu{100 g}$ of fertilizer.

Then, $\pu{2 kg}$ contains $20$ times $\pu{100 g}$. Here is your second mistake. So the total amount of nitrogen is $20 \cdot \pu{13.72 g} = \pu{274.4 g}$.

---

Note, $\pu{wt\%}$ describes *percentage by mass* equally known as [mass fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_percent).  There equally are $\pu{mol\%}$ about *mole fraction* and $\pu{vol\%}$ about *volume fraction*, too.

Comment: I suggest to carry the units whenever possible *within reason*.  A subsequent [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Checking_equations_that_involve_dimensions) is one of the tools available to check the results for plausibility and chemistry.se may be a vector to disseminate this technique to its readers.  On chemistry.se, the `\pu{}` syntax works reasonably well within equations, too; the occasional escaping of `%` is a small investment in addition.